# Optimal Control: Proof of Adjoint Lagrange method?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, lagrange-multiplier, dirac-delta, optimal-control

Consider an optimal control problem: Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f\in C^{0,1}([0,T]\times (\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m),E)$ be bounded, let the state equation be
$$\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x(t),u(t)),\, t\in[0,1], \quad x(0) = x_0.$$
Let $x_u$ be the unique state associated to a control $u$ and let the cost functional $J$ be defined in terms of the final state only: $J\colon u\mapsto c(x_u(1))$ where $c\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,[0,\infty))$.

An author proceeded as follows:
Consider the adjoint ODE
$$-\lambda(t) = \partial_2f(t,x_u(t),u(t))^T\lambda(t),\, t\in[0,1],\quad \lambda(1) = \partial c(x_u(1)).$$
Then, for controls $v$, it would be
$$\partial J(u)v = \int_0^1\lambda^T\partial_3f(t,x_u(t),u(t))v(t)dt,\quad t\in[0,1] \tag{1}$$
where $\partial J(u)$ refers to the Fréchet derivative of $J$ at $u$.

- Can I prove this without just accepting some loose argument like "consider an isolated change at $u(t)$" or go full-on into distribution theory? If yes how? Perhaps some limit argument with small changes locally at $u(t)$?
- W.r.t. to which norm on the space of controls do I need to assume $\partial J(u)$ to be computed. This is relevant because I'd like to identify $\lambda^T\partial_3f(t,x_u(t),u(t))$ as the gradient of $J$ in $u$.

Comment: Couple questions: Is $x_u$ associated with the *optimal* control, or *any* control? The notation with the $\partial$'s, is $\partial_3$ the partial wrt the third input on whatever follows? i.e. $\partial_3 f(t,x,u)$ is also $\partial_u f(t,x,u)$? Have you taken a closer look at the fact that $J$ is a function only of the terminal state? You'll still get a cost functional from adjoining, but not having a cost functional in the original problem might simplify your proof down a bit.

Comment: @MichaelSparapany Yes to the question on the notation of partial derivatives. By my premises every control $u$ uniquely determines a state that I call $x_u$, i.e. one could consider the mapping $u\mapsto x_u$ on some set of controls. Therefore, I'd still say that I have a cost functional in the original problem: $u$ determones $x_u$ which in turn determines the terminal state of $x_u$. Either way, I don't see how this would help me make the "consideration of isolated changes $\delta u(t_0)$ in the control $u$" rigorous. Thank you for the comment!